# MySQL Query from 3 tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have 3 tables.

```
Mark
id_mark
mark_name
```

example record:
1, 'Ford'

---

```
Model
id_model
id_mark
mondel_name
```

example record:
1, 1, 'Focus'

---

```
Adds
id_adds
id_model
name
price
etc.
```

example record:
1 1 'My ad', 20000

How to execute a query that returned result example:

```
My ad Ford Focus 20000
```

Comment: Do a join? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/join.html Have you got any code yet?

Comment: You want an INNER JOIN - have a look here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/join.html

Answer (score 1):

Using your exact spellings:

```
SELECT a.name, mk.mark_name, mo.mondel_name, a.price
FROM Adds a
INNER JOIN Model mo ON mo.id_model = a.id_model
INNER JOIN Mark mk ON mk.id_mark = mo.id_mark
```

Though instead of including `id_mark` in your `Model` table, I think you should have a join table that consists of nothing but `id_model` and `id_mark` and the key is comprised of both fields.

Answer (score 0):

```
select adds.id_model, mark.mark_name, model.model_name adds.price
from mark, model, adds
where model.id_mark = mark.id_mark and adds.id_model = model.id_model
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.name, ma.mark_name, mo.model_name, a.price
from adds a, mark ma, model mo
where a.id_model = mo.id_model
and ma.id_mark = mo.id_mark
```

Be carefull with the data model, if you query just like that and there is more than one mark for the model you gonna get something like

My ad Ford Focus 20000
My ad Fiat Focus 20000